# ArcGIS Enterprise Geodatabase - MSSQL Server Permisions & Schemes

Tags: arcgis-desktop, enterprise-geodatabase, sql-server

I have an active directory group called GIS_Admins. I have created a Server Login that points to this group and the group is mapped to a user for the appropriate database. The User has been made a member of db_owner and the default scheme is set to dbo.

For the most part this setup is working fine. Here is the issue. When a user connects to the Geodatabase using their windows authentication, if the user creates a new feature class it creates a scheme after their domain name. For example the feature class would be named "database.'domain\username'.FeatureclassName". I would like all feature classes created by members of this group to be created into the dbo scheme. What am I missing here?

Comment: How to create sde Geodatabase. Do you use Create enterprise geodatabase tool ? are you create sde using sa account?

Comment: Yes, the gdb was created using the tool. It was configured to use sde scheme and I created it using my account which is a sysadmin account.

Comment: Change the schema to dbo schema

Comment: Is it possible to switch once you have already created the gdb?

Comment: It's possible but you may be faced with another problems with the users. Create a new gdb with dbo schema is better than change the schema. Create a gdb with dbo schema and test it. If the problem solved, copy all of the data in the new gdb

Comment: The schema under which new feature classes and tables are created is NOT related to the option to create the geodatabase repository tables as owned by either the sde user or a WinAuth dbo user upon enterprise geodatabase creation. For your question, you need to adjust the schema that your database role uses. You should not attempt to recreate your geodatabase or any geodatabase tables to resolve this.